# Mobile site doesn't show monospace font for codeblocks

Tags: support, feature-request, code-formatting, mobile-web

When I visit stackoverflow on my phone (chrome browser on google nexus 5) the codeblocks are in a proportional width font.

Is there a way to make them display in fixed-width font please?

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924548/why-do-we-have-to-use-the-dunder-methods-instead-of-operators-when-calling-v):

[image: blah]

Comment: Working fine in MobileSafari.

Comment: yes having problem in android mobiles